# Using foreign key of the UserCreationForm model User

Tags: python, django

I have made a signup page using built in `UserCreationForm` of django.

**signup.html**

```
class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = EmailField(label=_("Email address"), required=True, help_text=_("Required."))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

But I also need to make other tables in `models.py`. So if in another table `category` I need to make a foreign key of the primary key of this built in User of `UserCreationForm`. What is the primary key in this?

**models.py**

```
class category(models.Model):
    uid = models.ForeignKey(#)
    cname = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{} {}".format(self.uid, self.cname)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "category"
```

What do I write in place of # ??

Comment: you should learn the difference between a form and a model. The form in no way influences the underlying model. You could have multiple different forms to create a user, all using the same model. Your user model is still just a standard django user, so your foreign key should point to the `User` model. Just import `User` and make a foreign key to it, or better, use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` which is the Django `User` by default but might be changed by you to your custom user model.

Comment: got it sir!!!thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just point to the `User` model:

```
from django.contrib.auth import User
uid = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

or better, in case you might want to customise the User model:

```
from django.conf import settings
uid = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```